# Get element without specific css class

Tags: jquery

i have a function like this, to get all Tr elements inside tbody tag that do not belong to the first Tr. Now i want to get such element without tr with s_gridview_pagerstyle css class. plz tell me how to modify this block code for running as expected.

Thankx!

```
if(arrayRequest.length>0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayRequest.length; i++) {
                $('.s_dashboard_table').find('tbody').children(':not(:first):eq(' + i + ')'.each(function () {

                    var td = $(this).children().first();
                    td.append("<input type='checkbox' name='exportedItem' class='cbxItem' value='" + arrayRequest[i] + "'/>");

                });
            }
    }
```

Comment: `:not(.s_gridview_pagerstyle)`

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: i did do like that : $('.s_dashboard_table').find('tbody').children(':not(:first):eq(' + i + '):not(.s_gridview_pagerstyle)').each(function () {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$("tr:not(.s_gridview_pagerstyle)")
```

**UPDATE**

```
$("table.s_dashboard_table tr:not(.s_gridview_pagerstyle)").each(function(key, value){
    var td = $(this).children().first();
    td.append("<input type='checkbox' name='exportedItem' class='cbxItem' value='" + arrayRequest[i] + "'/>");
});
```

Comment: i want to add more condition for this block code above. if use your code, where i can put in??

Comment: What kind of condition do you want to use ? I can modify but I don't know what conditions you want

Comment: $('.s_dashboard_table').find('tbody').children(':not(:first):eq(' + i + ')'. this code block is used for getting TR that is not the first. now i like to add more condition for this. specifically, i dont want to get TR that has s_gridview_pagerstyle CSS class. :)

Comment: your code is not my desire. let's me tell u about it. Find all TR in the tbody of the table with s_dashboard_table class.
those TR cannot be in the first position && don't have the s_gridview_pagerstyle class. thank you for your support :)

Comment: what is this? letting somebody do your work? for free? show us what you have tried

Comment: @Mark: i decided to change the way i approach it. i just use server controls and handle event by jquery. this is much more easier than generating client controls, and handle events for them, since I'm not good at jquery and javascript in general.